# Android support library v7 appcompat incomplete

Tags: c#, android

I have just started learning xamarin and visual studio developing an android c# app now i have an error in the main activity class when i try to reference AppCompatActivity it says its not found i tried adding the library on components but its says its incomplete, even tried adding it using nuget but i still get the error. I checked my xamarin folder in c/users/xamarin for files referencing this library but the are no files and i have deleted the one in nuget but i still get the same error.

Comment: Paste the compilation error you are getting

Comment: Did you hit this? https://blog.lextudio.com/2016/05/android-support-repository-and-xamarin-android/

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'AppCompatActivity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ToDoList C:\Users\nphiliso\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ToDoList\ToDoList\MainActivity.cs 8 Active
this is the error i am getting in the mainactivity class when i try to use appcompatactivity

Comment: I have checked the blog but in my xamarin folder i dont have a zip folder

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.   0

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the xamarin.android.support libraries were restructured.

I had the same problem but when i add xamarin.android.support.design via nuget package, automatically where added xamarin.android.support.transition and xamarin.android.support.v7.recyclerview whith that the AppCompatActivity class appears.

I hope it works for others.